# subquery is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

This is my mysql query

```
  SELECT tm.MAGAZINE_ID, tm.MAGAZINE_NAME,tm.MAGAZINE_DESCRIPTION,pub.publisher_name,
                tmi.COVER_PAGE_THUMB AS COVER_PAGE_VERTICAL,tmi.FROM_DATE AS ISSUE_DATE,
                tm.html_flag AS HTML_EXIST,tm.CATEGORY_ID,tm.language_id,tm.is_free,tma.AppUrl,
                (SELECT issue_id from tbl_magazine_issue WHERE magazine_id = 141
                ORDER BY FROM_DATE DESC LIMIT 1) as temp_issue_id
            FROM tbl_magazine_apps as tma
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_magazine_code as tmc ON tmc.Code = tma.AppsCode
                LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_magazine` AS tm ON tmc.magazine_Id = tm.MAGAZINE_ID 
                JOIN `tbl_magazine_issue` AS tmi ON temp_issue_id = tmi.issue_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_publisher AS pub ON tm.publisher_id=pub.publisher_id 
            WHERE
                tmi.PUBLISH_STATUS IN(1,3) 
                AND tmi.`OS_SELECT` = '".$osType."' 
                AND tma.id IN (".$appIds.")
                GROUP BY tm.MAGAZINE_ID
                ORDER BY tmi.ISSUE_DATE DESC
```

but i got an error that

```
  #1054 - Unknown column 'temp_issue_id' in 'on clause'
```

if any one know about this please help me. i am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK The subquery belongs to the from part:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html
So I would join the subquery.

Like:

```
SELECT a.a, b.b
FROM table1 as a
JOIN (SELECT b from table2) as b ON a.key = b.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggests, the column `temp_issue_id` is not in any of the following tables:  `tbl_magazine_apps`, `tbl_magazine`, or `tbl_magazine_issue`.  It is also not a variable in the environment.

Beyond that, it is pretty much impossible for anyone to figure out how to fix the problem without more knowledge about the data structure.

If I were to hazard a guess, based on the table names, that particular join would be:

```
            JOIN `tbl_magazine_issue` AS tmi ON tm.magazine_id = tmi.magazine_id
```

because it makes sense to me that a magazine issue would be connect to a magazine.  I have no idea what `temp_issue_id` is, though.

Answer (score 0):

`temp_issue_id` give alias name for specifying this column i think it should be `tm.issue_id`

Answer (score 0):

temp_issue_id is column's name as per the query. You need it to convert to table and use subsequent column in your SELECT clause.